# How to draw a simple class object in Java(JFrame)?

Tags: java, swing, draw

I am quite new to Java application development and I want to draw some simple shapes in the JFrame-canvas without using one main class but rather split it into a main class and a class playerRectangle. In the playerRectangle class I created a method paint:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
       setSize(500, 500);
       g.drawRect(320, 20, 640, 120);
   }
```

I then created an object in some render funtion in the main class and called the paint function of this object.

```
playerRectangle p1 = new playerRectangle();
p1.paint(null);
```

But somehow it threw the java.lang.NullPointerException error and didn't render the rect to the screen. When I don't split this function into two classes it works properly even though it throws this error. So please help me and tell me, what I am missing here.

Any research on Youtube and other stuff only told me that I have to create classes like screen etc. but I am not so sure that is helping me.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Show your window class and playerRectangle class, and how do you drawing rectangle when everything in the one class?

Comment: _I am quite new to Java application development_ Have you considered using _JavaFX_ instead of _Swing_? _JavaFX_ is supposed to be a more modern replacement for _Swing_. Since you claim to be just starting out, why not go with the most up-to-date API?

Comment: _Swing_ is about twenty (20) years old. You need to try and make sure you aren't looking at ancient and outdated tutorials on the Internet. (Assuming you want to stick with _Swing_ rather than going with _JavaFX_)

Comment: [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: @Abra Agree, as well as coding in terminal, but usually professors require to do home work using ancient technology :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple example how to draw Rectangle using  standard libraries :

```
public class SomeClass extends JPanel {
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  g.fillRect(0,0,320,220);
 }
 SomeClass() {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   frame.serContentPane(this);
   frame.setBounds(0,0,320,220);
   frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Class with main method:

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new SomeClass();
 }
}
```